# Algo for payment device amount suggestion for cash payment

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming

I have done knapsack problems, etc but I am not sure if this problem somehow falls in that area and regardless of that, how to solve it. Here is the question:

`Suppose we are given a set of denominations {1, 2, 10, 20, 50, 100}. A customer is checking out and is paying in cash. How we suggest the top 6 or top x choices on our own payment screen based on what amount the customer may have handed over. For example if customer has to pay 87$, customer might hand over 5 bills of 100, or 4 bills of 20 and a 5 and a 2, etc` I am not able to come up with an algo, though I keep getting the feeling it is around knapsack problem but with multiple answers for a given value?

Comment: How will you decide that these are the top 6 choices to pay an amount, using dp you can calculate how many ways are there to pay an amount using the above denominations, let's say 8 ways are there to pay the amount $87 using the above denominations but how can we decide that these are the top 6 choices etc... Should we sort our choices based on the usage of how many high denomination amounts are used ?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. What makes the choice better than others? Is 5x100 better then 4x80+1x20+1x5+x2 or other way around? How exactly is decided which options are "top"?

Comment: @libik, the Q was vaguely framed even when I was asked but one metric can be to use less number of bills or the nearest sum one is the top choice or a blend of both. for 87: choice 1: 4x20+2+5, choice 2: 4*20+10, choice 3: 5*x20

Comment: @zenwraight, the customer rarely pays an exact amount but that can be one choice for sure, and I responded to similar Q by libik on top choices.

Comment: @curiousengineer if time complexity is not a constraint, then for a given input amount n, you can run a recursive function also, that will go through all the combinations and give you the answer of different ways.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to mention is that you should get more specific requirements. It is really important to sit with client, prepare examples and ask them questions: "I have to pay 87, I give you 87x$1, is it good or not and why". From more obvious you get to: "whats better 50x2 or 50+20+20 and why". To create algorithm of anything, you first need to be able to say how would you proceed as a human (with unlimited time and lot of patience) and then you can implement it.

One quite straightforward metric here is that you want value as close as possible to real amount and also you dont want to pay with too much bills, right?

So we have to find all the solutions, then count score (less bills and more close to target value the better), sort by the score and take 'x' of best ones.

You can upgrade the "score" function with i.e. "10 and 20" bills are preferred so they give you better score using them. Or the lower amount of bills is more important than the difference between target value and sum of your bills, so you penalize the bills more (like each $10 difference has same penalization as 1 bill more)

This is working javascript code based on backtracking.

```js
// const countables = [100, 50, 20, 10, 2, 1];
// const targetAmount = 87;

const countables = [5, 2, 1];
const targetAmount = 13;


const payments = [];
const solutions = [];
let index = 0;

let end = false;
let i = 0;

while (end === false) {
    const sum = payments.reduce((prev, val) => prev + val, 0);
    if (sum >= targetAmount) {
        solutions.push({
            sum,
            score: countTheScore(payments, targetAmount, sum),
            payments: [...payments],
        })
        index++;
        if (index === countables.length) {
            let popped = null;
            do {
                popped = payments.pop();
            } while (popped === countables[countables.length - 1]);
            if (payments.length === 0) {
                end = true;
            }
            const indexOfLastNonLowest = countables.indexOf(popped);
            index = indexOfLastNonLowest + 1;
        } else {
            payments.pop();
        }
    } else {
        payments.push(countables[index]);
    }
}


function countTheScore(payments, targetAmount, sum) {
    amount = payments.length;
    difference = sum - targetAmount;
    return amount + difference;
}

console.log(solutions.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score));
// const sortedSolutions = solutions.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);
// const bestSolutions = [];
// for (var j=0; j < 5; j++) {
//     bestSolutions.push(sortedSolutions[j]);
// }
// console.log(bestSolutions);
```

It has this output of all solutions sorted from best to worst:

```
[ { sum: 13, score: 4, payments: [ 5, 5, 2, 1 ] },
  { sum: 15, score: 5, payments: [ 5, 5, 5 ] },
  { sum: 14, score: 5, payments: [ 5, 5, 2, 2 ] },
  { sum: 13, score: 5, payments: [ 5, 5, 1, 1, 1 ] },
  { sum: 13, score: 5, payments: [ 5, 2, 2, 2, 2 ] },
  { sum: 13, score: 6, payments: [ 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1 ] },
  { sum: 13, score: 7, payments: [ 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] },
  { sum: 13, score: 8, payments: [ 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] },
  { sum: 13, score: 9, payments: [ 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] } ]
```

(lower the score the better)

For your original requirements, this would be the output of best 5:

```
[ { sum: 90, score: 6, payments: [ 50, 20, 20 ] },
  { sum: 90, score: 7, payments: [ 50, 20, 10, 10 ] },
  { sum: 87, score: 7, payments: [ 50, 20, 10, 2, 2, 2, 1 ] },
  { sum: 87, score: 8, payments: [ 50, 10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 1 ] },
  { sum: 90, score: 8, payments: [ 50, 10, 10, 10, 10 ] } ]
```

---

btw: If I change the score function to

```
function countTheScore(payments, targetAmount, sum) {
    amount = payments.length*3;
    difference = sum - targetAmount;
    return amount + difference;
}
```

Then the output would be probably more accurate to what you need

```
[ { sum: 90, score: 12, payments: [ 50, 20, 20 ] },
  { sum: 90, score: 15, payments: [ 50, 20, 10, 10 ] },
  { sum: 100, score: 16, payments: [ 100 ] },
  { sum: 90, score: 18, payments: [ 50, 10, 10, 10, 10 ] },
  { sum: 100, score: 19, payments: [ 50, 50 ] } ]
```

You can play a little more with these metrics and finding out what has the best output for you.

Comment: amazing answer and you got the requirement correct. I don't know much javascript, may I ask what is ``payments.reduce`` doing?

Comment: @curiousengineer - You dont have to know the exact syntax (you can google it - javascript array reduce). But it counts the sum of all the values in `payments` array. So if you just for-cycle it and `sum += payments[i]`, it would be the same. But with reduce, its one-liner.